# How do I replace matched regular expression without including the final character in XCode?

Tags: xcode

I've got a number of places in files for a project with the following format: `func whatever() ->Bool {`.  However, it looks like the standard Swift guide is to use `func nevermind() -> String` (note the space between the `->` and the start of the return type).

I am able to find all these instances by using `Regular Expression` option in the Replace sidebar with `->[^ ]`.  However, this includes the first character of the return type.  What should I type in the replace field to insert a space without bothering the next non-space character?

Comment: Something like this is better suited for Stack Overflow, even though it's about app development for Apple products. You'll get better answers there.

Comment: Any good way to copy this over to there without having to markup the formatting again?
(I realised I could brute-force my way by matching all instances of `->` and replacing them with `-> `, then matching any `->  ` to catch the ones that over-corrected).